# ruby alternative to delete_if/reject to remove items from array

Tags: ruby

I am aware of the following two methods to remove items from array:

```
a.delete_if {|x| x >= "b" } 
array.reject {|x| x < 3}
```

But neither of them suite my needs. I need a way to specify a clean way to identify the items to remove from the array. Something like this:

```
Model.column_names # => [:age, :name, :created_at, :updated_at]
Model.column_names.discard :created_at, :updated_at
Model.column_names # => [:age, :name]
```

where discard could take an unlimited amount of symbols.

Comment: You need it, but you haven't showed us that you've tried to write it. That makes it sound like you're fishing for someone else to write it for you. Instead, show us what you've tried and describe why it didn't work.

Comment: @theTinMan I could easily make my own such method, but I was anticipating something already built in, such as "-=" below.

Comment: That may be, however, on Stack Overflow, by consensus, it's agreed that questions should show what has been tried previously, which helps rule out those "feed me code" questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about?

```
Model.column_names # => [:age, :name, :created_at, :updated_at]
Model.column_names -= [:created_at, :updated_at]
Model.column_names # => [:age, :name]
```

Comment: That is correct. - and + are overloaded for arrays to append and remove items respectively.

Answer (score 1):

There is this way with [reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-reject)...

```
Model.column_names.reject {|x| [:created_at, :updated_at].include?(x) }
```

Another way would be with [select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select)...

```
Model.column_names.select {|x| not [:created_at, :updated_at].include?(x) }
```